# How To Get Google Maps link From Current location?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I need to get the google maps link by pressing a button from the iPhone.

I already know how to get the coordinate long/lang. Now I need to convert it to a link.

I am working with `CLLocation` & `MKMapview`

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Several of these [previous SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Google+maps+URL+iPhone) tell how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the "Apple URL Schemes" documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html). Everything about map links is detailed in this page.

Answer (score 2):

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=38.323480,26.767732

You can change those variables at the end and the link will open the google maps app no need for complicated programming

Comment: You are kidding, right? You don't seem to have read the question at all.